# Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{tabularx}

Tags: tabularx

Good morning, i'm trying to create a table using tabularx package. I get this error:

```
Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \NC@find. \end{tabularx}
```

Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{tabularx}

I think i'm closing brackets and all the commands beginned are ended. What am i missing?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\captionsetup{
    justification = centering
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=2cm, % Top margin
    bottom=2cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l cccc @{}} 
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{ c }{{\bfseries PISTOIA AREA}} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & \multicolumn{1}{P}{5 cells}
    & \multicolumn{1}{P}{7 cells}  
    & \multicolumn{1}{P}{11 cells} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{P@{}}{21 cells} \\ 
    Slope  &&& X &\\ 
    Longitudinal curv.  &&&&  X \\ 
    Cross sectional curv.  &&&& X \\ 
    \midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The first line of the .log code is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.30)  31 AUG 2019 12:10
entering extended mode
```

Comment: Please show the complete log file, there must be another issue, because I can compile without problems. perhaps you have a local version of `tabularx` or simular. That we can see only in the complete log file. Use pastebin, if it is too large to be added to your question ...

Comment: What is the purpose of `tabularx` if there are no cells that would require automatic linebreaks? Wouldn't a normal `tabular` (or `tabular*` if you insist on stretching the tabular to textwidth) be sufficient? Also, why are the table headers left aligned and the contents centered? With the very wide table cells the contents do not look like they were aligned with the corresponding column header.

Comment: @Mensch https://pastebin.com/XSSqpR4i

Comment: @leandriis thanks for your reply. So should i only use tabular instead of tabularx? i would like to center everything (headers and contents)

Comment: @Elisam: What environment to use depends on the desired output:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBovh.png First table is yours, second is done with `tabular`, thisr id sith `tabular*`.

Comment: Your shown log file is **not** the log file of the given code in your question, it is the log file of your complete document I do not know the code. So it is not very helpful. Please make sure we talk about the same code: First we have to get the given mwe in your question to be compilable, then you can have a look to your document for differencies. So please compile the given MWE in your question three times and show the resulting log file ... BTW: why do you have two different definitions for P? Comment the first one `%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`  and compile.

Comment: And read the warnings carefully in the log file of your original document: you have double or more defined same labels for figures. Correct that! Each figure has an unique label, only seen one time in the complete document ...

Comment: @Mensch i corrected the errors for the table and figure labels.

Comment: Okay, and does the given MWE compile? If not please show the log file resulting from compiling the MWE ...

Comment: A reference for people having the same error in other contexts https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/782